# compiler reports const instead of const&

Tags: c++

Tried to compile following code, can't understand error message.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
struct S {
    string a{"abc"};
    const string& data() { return a; }
};
int main() {
    S s;
    int a = s.data(); // error: no viable conversion from 'const std::string' to 'int'
    return 0;
}
```

Question: why does compiler say 'const std::string' instead of 'const std::string&'?

Tried with Apple clang 14.0.0 and g++ 12, same error message.

Comment: Expressions in C++ never have a reference type. See dupe: [Does each expression in C++ have a non-reference type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67415226/does-each-expression-in-c-have-a-non-reference-type)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`data()` returns a *reference* to a `const std::string` object, yes. But, you are not converting the reference itself to an `int`, you are converting the `std::string` object that it refers to.

A reference is just an alias, once a reference has been bound to an object, any access of the reference is really accessing the object instead.

That is why the error message does not include `&`.

Answer (score 2):

Expressions (such as `s.data()`) [never have reference types](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.type#1).

`&` is silently removed from the type, and, in case of a function call, dictates the value category of the resulting expression (lvalue in this case).